# perl put array element into hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have an array with a bunch of strings as elements, and I want to put then into hash. So I spilt the strings in the array first and then put the parsed strings into a new array call parse_list.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
my %hash;

my $string_array = [
                "Europe West France Spain Germany",
                "Europe North Finland Iceland",
                "Asia East Japan Korea China",
                "America North Mexico USA Canada"
    ];

foreach my $country(@{$string_array}){ 
    my @parse_list = split(/\s+/, $country);
    (my $continent,my $region,) = @parse_list[0,1];
    #I just know how to get the continent and region, I don't know how to put       
    #the element from index [2..4] to an array 

}
```

How can I set

**Continent** as the primary key and the **Region** as the value in the first layer of the hash.

**Region** as the secondary key and the array **Country** as the value in the second layer of the hash.

so it is like

```
my %hash = (
    Europe => {
        West => [ "France", "Spain", "Germany"]
        }
    );
```

Comment: `my ($continent,$region,@rest) = @parse_list; $hash{$continent}{$region} = \@rest;`

Comment: @Сухой27 it works!! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're "parsing" your list, it's not very helpful to store everything in a single array. Instead, put the data into more useful variables.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $string_array = [
  "Europe West France Spain Germany",
  "Europe North Finland Iceland",
  "Asia East Japan Korea China",
  "America North Mexico USA Canada"
];

my %geography;

for (@$string_array) {
  my ($continent, $region, @countries) = split;

  $geography{$continent}{$region} = \@countries;
}

print Dumper \%geography;
```

The output is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'America' => {
                         'North' => [
                                      'Mexico',
                                      'USA',
                                      'Canada'
                                    ]
                       },
          'Europe' => {
                        'West' => [
                                    'France',
                                    'Spain',
                                    'Germany'
                                  ],
                        'North' => [
                                     'Finland',
                                     'Iceland'
                                   ]
                      },
          'Asia' => {
                      'East' => [
                                  'Japan',
                                  'Korea',
                                  'China'
                                ]
                    }
        };
```

**Update** (to add some more explanation):

I've changed the name of `%hash` to `%geography` - naming variables well is very important.

When using the `for (...)` construct, it's often useful to use Perl's default behaviour and store the list elements in `$_`. This is because `$_` is often the default input variable for various operations. In this case, for example, I could have written:

```
for my $geo (@$string_array) {
  my ($continent, $region, @countries) = split /\s+/, $geo;
  ...
}
```

But the `split` function works on `$_` by default. And, even better, its standard behaviour is to split on `/\s+/`, so we can omit all that too and end up with much cleaner code:

```
for (@$string_array) {
  my ($continent, $region, @countries) = split;
  ...
}
```

Comment: it works pretty well!. Thanks for solving my problem. :)

Comment: @Luke: Glad to hear it works "pretty well" :-/ Hope you learned something from reading it.